# Selecting an element located inside a different container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Example code:

```
<div id="container-1">
    <div class="element-1"></div>
    <div class="element-2"></div>
    ...
</div>

<div id="container-2">
    <div class="element-3"></div>
    <div class="element-4"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

I'm trying to apply a hover effect to an element located inside the second container when I hover over an element from the first container. Both elements have to be in different containers.

The closest thing I managed to achieve is:

```
#container-1:hover ~ #container-2 .element-3
```

This selector allows me to apply a hover effect to .element-3 when I hover over the first container, however I would like to make it work only when I hover over one of the elements inside the container, not the entire container itself.

Basically, something similar to the following: (which sadly doesn't seem to work)

```
#container-1 .element-1:hover ~ #container-2 .element-3
```

Is there any way I could accomplish this using only pure css?

Comment: No, because CSS doesn't have a parent selector. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/3187556

Comment: Upvotes on a parent-selector question ?

Comment: Better to use jQuery hover event